# Django: Search via GET request, POST request or in the URL?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a search form in Django. I can do a POST or a GET request. Each has their use-cases (POST request, if I want to change data on the server, GET request, if I just want to get data from the server).

- Via POST request (the search keywords are not visiable in the URL, but rather in a dict in request.POST); cons: I cannot bookmark the search
- via GET request (the search keywords are visible in the URL, for intance `localhost:8000/books/?author=schultz`); cons(?): the part `?author=schultz` cannot be processed by the URL handler (see [2] below). I need to read the data from `request.GET.get("author", None)` in my view function.
- or directly in the URL like so: `localhost:8000/books/search/author/schultz` ?

The author in [1] says, that Django's preferred way to handle a URL is not via GET (like so: `/category_check_view/?item_id=2`, but rather like so `/category_check_view/2`)

If I would like to implement search like this: `localhost:8000/books/author/schultz`, then I would have to process a GET request, read the params `?author=schultz` via `request.GET.get("author", None)` and in my view do a redirect from this URL `localhost:8000/books` (in which I have a form and a GET request) to this `localhost:8000/books/author/schultz`.

Does this approach make sense? Or am I overcomplicating things? Just leave it at a GET request to implement my search form?

---

[1] [Yuval Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24545/yuval-adam) says in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398231/5115219) that

> GET params are not processed by the URL handler, but rather passed
>   directly to the GET param dict accessible in a view at request.GET.
>
> The Django (i.e. preferred) way to do handle URLs is the first one.

[2] [Django docs: What the URLconf searches against](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against)

Comment: I don't understand how you will modify data while searching. Search in most  of the use cases are done using GET request.

Comment: I didn't say that I wanted to modify data. Just that it would be possible to do it via POST request, if I didn't want the search keywords to show up in the URL or in the log files etc

Comment: I can't see the need for the redirect. The point of a search is that it can accept multiple parameters, and displays the result of the combined lookup. There's no need to redirect anywhere.

Comment: So you'd always use a GET request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, **GET** is for reading data and **POST** is for creating. Since search is a form of reading data, you will use **GET**!

Which takes us to the matter of the urls. There are as you mention 2 distinct ways to pass parameters via a url in Django:

1. **Parameters as part of url:**

   Your url regex must look like this:

   ```
   url(r'^books/author/(?P<author>\w+)/$', 
       'yourviewname', 
       name='author_search'
   )
   ```

   Your URLs will have the shape: `/books/author/author_name_here`
2. **GET Parameters:**

   Your url regex can look like this:

   ```
   url(r'^books/$', 
       'yourviewname', 
       name='book_search'
   )
   ```

   Your URLs will have the shape: `/books/?author=author_name_here&other=other_param`

It is a matter of choice mostly on what you want to use. To quote [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559996/post-vs-get-method-for-a-search-form-in-cms?answertab=votes#tab-top):

> Don't obsess over the beauty of your URIs, they are a tool not a piece of art.
>    - @Quentin -

---

*For a short implementation example of both the above mentioned ways, take a look at [this link](http://django.cowhite.com/blog/working-with-url-get-post-parameters-in-django/)*

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks! Now if I wanted to implement it with parameters as part of the URL (your first example), would the logic be like this? I would have a `books/` page where I have a search form. Now after submitting the search form would I redirect to `books/author/(searchword)` ? Or how else would I connect the two URLs `books/` and `books/author/(searchword)`. - I am not saying that I prefer doing search that way. Just wondered which way is the idiomatic way to go.

Comment: @Ugur You do not need to redirect anywhere! Your view can simply return the query's result and that would be all (That is how I do it in either case!). :)

Comment: But the search happens on this page `books/`. And if the view reads the searchword from `request.GET.get("searchword", None)`, how does my URL (suddenly) show `books/author/(searchword)`. Even if the search happened on this page `books/author/`, after submit, how does the URL reflect `books/author/(searchword)`? Am I missing something fundamentally? :)

Comment: @Ugur have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661044/how-to-redirect-url-pattern-with-variables-from-urls-py-in-django?answertab=votes#tab-top It may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Also usable is:

```
from django.urls import path

import <your_view> from views.py

path('news/<str:author>/', <your_view>.as_view())
```